# Access sql query Circular Reference error

Tags: sql, ms-access, alias, circular-reference

I'm creating a sql select query for an access database, and receiving a circular reference error, because my alias name is the same as a column name in my expression. Here is the fragment of my query:

```
switch([CULET]='N','NONE', [CULET]='S', 'SMALL',[CULET]='VS','VERY SMALL', [CULET]='SL','  ',[CULET]='MD','  ') AS [Culet]
```

This specific alias name is part of the requirements for the output. Is there any way to get around this without changing the alias name?

TIA

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the *table name/alias* to the field. Something like

```
Switch([Table1.CULET]='N','NONE',[Table1.CULET]='S','SMALL',[Table1.CULET]='VS','VERY SMALL',[Table1.CULET]='SL','  ',[Table1.CULET]='MD','  ') AS Culet
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this error can occur when the circular reference is actually within one of the queries used as the basis of the query you are working on (even when the basis query actually doesn't raise any errors, itself!) In this case, you should follow the [recommendations in Microsoft's KB (knowledge-base) article 97526](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/97526), for the basis query.